# How do I make variables change outside functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner with Javascript/programming and I am trying to make the "demo2" id change with the 5, 10 or 15 variable chosen in the functions (trigger by the buttons), but it keeps showing "0". What do I have to do?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <body>
      <button onclick="alternative1()">5</button>
        <button onclick="alternative2()">10</button>
          <button onclick="alternative3()">15</button>
          
          <p id="demo"></p>
          <p id="demo2"></p>
    
      <script>
       
       var x = 0;
       var y = 0;
      
    
        function alternative1() {y = x + 5;
          
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You have chosen " + y;
        } 
        
        
        function alternative2() {y = x + 10;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You have chosen "+ y;
        }
        
        
        function alternative3() {y = x + 15;
          
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You have chosen "+ y;
        }
        
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
        
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This code is actually running as expected in https://jsfiddle.net/2kotnwrg/

Answer (score 0):

You can’t access variables declared inside a function from outside a function. The variable belongs to the function’s scope only, not the global scope.

Comment: The variables are declared outside the function so they should be global.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 3 functions for this.  You can do it with 1.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <body>
      <button onclick="alternative(this)">5</button>
        <button onclick="alternative(this)">10</button>
          <button onclick="alternative(this)">15</button>
          
          <p id="demo"></p>
    
      <script>
        function alternative(obj) {          
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You have chosen " + obj.innerHTML;
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Happy learning

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that there is zero because in 'y' there is zero and no operation performed on y.

I hope that this answer will help you to understand what you have done.

Comment: Each function has a 'y = ' operation.  And the code runs as is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 'demo2 inner' after every operation and need to add new value to 'y' current value (use +=)

```js
 var x = 0;
       var y = 0;
      
    
        function alternative(param) {
          y += x + param;
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You have chosen "+ param;
          document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
        }
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <body>
      <button onclick="alternative(5)">5</button>
        <button onclick="alternative(10)">10</button>
          <button onclick="alternative(15)">15</button>
          
          <p id="demo"></p>
          <p id="demo2"></p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```